# Submit POST Data Without Using DOM

Tags: javascript, http, post, web-worker

In javascript, I need to send some POST data, but I can't access DOM, which rules out things like making dummy DOM forms, FormData or JQuery.

I've searched and tried, and the best I can come up with is

```
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","//example.org",false);
xhr.send("foo=bar&bah=baz&pipe=%7C")
```

This works, but the server sends back an error. I'm not sure whether this is a logic error (i.e. I'm not talking to the server right), or whether I'm getting something wrong in the HTTP. Is this the right way to send POST data, and if not, what is?

Comment: And what is this error you're referring to ?

Comment: You can create a _FormData_ without using a `<form>`, just use `new FormData` to create an empty one, then `append` your desired data. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: @adeneo Doesn't specify. It returns a 200 saying error.

Comment: @user1277170 sounds like the error is server-side, are you sure that it actually accepts these as a _POST_?

Comment: @PaulS. Note that FormData needs to access DOM, so it can't be used. If I'm doing everything right here, I'll take another look at the server parameters, etc. I wanted to make sure that it wasn't a protocol issue. (And that escaping is done correctly.)

Comment: @user1277170 I didn't see the _DOM_ mentioned any more than it is for _XMLHttpRequest_ as I skimmed the _FormData_ spec on [**w3c**](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#interface-formdata) and [**whatwg**](http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-formdata). The constructor parameter entirely is _optional_ and you can work entirely with just _String_ if you want. I can understand that your environment may not support the interface, though.

Comment: @PaulS. FormData is undefined in a webworker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like adding

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

before sending solves the problem.